# C++ Why can't write this constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to ask this question...
Why we can't use Camera c1(20); ???

This is making class.
But we find the error in Camera c1(20);

Please let me know...

```
#include <iostream>

class Camera{
private:
public:
    Camera(){

    }
    Camera(int x){

    }
};

class Phone{
private:
    Camera c1(20);
public:

};

int main(){

}
```

Comment: To avoid parsing issue in general, you may use `Camera c1{20};` or `Camera c1 = Camera(20);`

Comment: please post the error message

Comment: Disagree with duplicate because in this question initialization is requested with constant value, not (ambiguous) identifier. While answer may be almost the same, question is different to me.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The problem is *any expression* in the `()`, how a compiler complains about the resulting ill-formed program is implementation defined.

Comment: @caleth I finally agree, that's grammar not a semantic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid parsing issue in general (See most vexing parse),

You may use `Camera c1{20};` or `Camera c1 = Camera(20);`